# Get an object from unique identifier(memory location, id etc)

Tags: python, scripting, objects

First of all, I'm new to blender scripting.

I'm looking for a way to uniquely identify an object, something that will reference the same object regardless of renames or any other changes in the scene.

I noticed that blender can give me the memory location where the object is stored and it doesn't seem to change. ('<bpy_struct, Object("Cube1") at **0x0000016BAD418108**>')

Is there any way to  turn this into an object that I can then use in my script?

Thank you!

Comment: Alright, so what I actually wanted to make was a mesh sequence object. I needed to have a list of references to different meshes in the sequence, but apparently I can just have a list of mesh objects(that update automatically on rename and deletion) as a custom property, so that's cool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the most popular way to identify the object is using custom props. The workflow is:

Register prop in add-on registration:

```
bpy.types.Object.myObjectID = bpy.props.StringProperty(name='My Object ID')
```

Use string or int, up to you.

Then use it then it's needed:

```
bpy.context.active_object.myObjectID = "ID 1"
```

or

```
m = bpy.data.meshes.new('MyMesh')
obj = bpy.data.objects.new("MyMesh",m)
obj.myObjectID = "ID 1"
```

On add-on unregister, disable prop:

```
bpy.props.RemoveProperty(bpy.types.Object, "myObjectID")
```

or

```
del bpy.types.Object.myObjectID
```